# CSS responsive query hide the content until user click on

Tags: jquery, html, css

I'm trying to create a div that will show up its content if screen max-width: 480px is.

But when I scale the window it appears even if user doesn't click on trigger button. How could I hide a specific div tag at first, at least until the user click on it? Could it be done with jquery or CSS?

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".slide-toggle").click(function() {
    $(".box").slideToggle();
  });
});
```

```css
@media only screen and (max-width: 480px) {
  .box {
    display: block;
  }
  .box-inner {
    width: 100%;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    display: block;
  }
  .slide-toggle {
    display: block;
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button type="button" class="slide-toggle">Slide Toggle</button>
<hr>
<div class="box">
  <div class="box-inner">
    <p> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nam eu sem tempor, varius quam at, luctus dui.</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: pls try .box {display: none;}

Comment: you need another CSS rule for > 480px that defaults the "box" class to "display:none;", if you don't want it displayed at all on bigger screens.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can achieve what you want without adding any further jquery, only css

see the snippet:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".slide-toggle").click(function() {
    $(".box").slideToggle();
  });
});
```

```css
.slide-toggle {
  display: none;
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 480px) {
  .box-inner {
    width: 100%;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    display: block;
  }
  .box {
    display: none;
  }
  .slide-toggle {
    display: block;
  }
}

@media only screen and (min-width: 481px) {
  .box {
    display: block!important;
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button type="button" class="slide-toggle">Slide Toggle</button>
<hr>
<div class="box">
  <div class="box-inner">
    <p> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nam eu sem tempor, varius quam at, luctus dui.</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Yeah that code works like a charm but I maybe forgot to tell or you skipped, this time box content appears when I resize the window full screen.

Comment: @DaF-Student Yeah i meant to do that ... show box in full screen and hide it in small screen and in small screen you show it with button ... and button is hidden in full screen but shown in small screen , that is what i did, isn't the case?

Comment: Sure, I was trying to place some links inside the div tag called box-inner and style it for small screens and big screens separately. I Think the rest can be done only with CSS, right?

Comment: @DaF-Student ... yes styling according to the screen size can be done with CSS only, no need for javascript

Comment: Thank you for the answer, I'll accept your solution.

Answer (score 1):

This is how I usually do it.

Hide the element initially with CSS:

```
#div_selector { display:none; }
```

Then, display it with jquery on click

```
$('#click_element').on('click', function(){ 
      $('#div_selector').show()

      //alternatively, you can do this to show/hide toggle on click
      $('#div_selector').toggle('show')          
 });
```

Answer (score 0):

do this after your document ready

```
$(".box").hide();
```

and on  the click event you just show it again:

```
$(".box").show();
```

Comment: actually I don't have clear idea on how to use "on click event" and "document ready function", but I'll try to learn anyway.